# Java int doesn't update. It resets

Tags: java, int

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class test {

    public static void main(String args[]){

        int a = 1000;
        while(a>0){

            System.out.println("Question to prevent infinite while loop");

            Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);

            int inzet = input.nextInt();

            System.out.println(a);
            test(a);

         }  


    }

    public static void test(int a){


        System.out.println(a);
        a = a + 100;
        System.out.println(a);



        }
    }
```

I have a question. Why does `int a` not update? It resets to 1000 every time. I don't want that. Can someone please help me? If I run the program I get this:

```
Question to prevent infinite while loop
2
1000
1000
1100
Question to prevent infinite while loop
2
1000
1000
1100
Question to prevent infinite while loop
2
1000
1000
1100
```

I want to get this code:

```
Question to prevent infinite while loop
2
1000
1000
1100
Question to prevent infinite while loop
2
1100
1100
1200
Question to prevent infinite while loop
2
1200
1200
1300
```

Also, this is my first post ever. Please give me some feedback about how I can ask my question better next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your updated value is only visible within your `test` method. You can either make `a` a field in combination with removing your current declaration (both in your `main`method as well as in your `test` arguments):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class test {

  private static int a = 1000;

  public static void main(String args[]) {

    while (a > 0) {
      System.out.println("Question to prevent infinite while loop");

      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

      int inzet = input.nextInt();

      System.out.println(a);
      test();
    }
  }

  public static void test() {
    System.out.println(a);
    a = a + 100;
    System.out.println(a);
  }
}
```

Or you can return the updated value from your method in combination with assigning the returned value to `a`:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class test {

  public static void main(String args[]) {

    int a = 1000;
    while (a > 0) {
      System.out.println("Question to prevent infinite while loop");

      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

      int inzet = input.nextInt();

      System.out.println(a);
      a = test(a);
    }
  }

  public static int test(int a) {
    System.out.println(a);
    a = a + 100;
    System.out.println(a);
    return a;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make `a` class property like this:

```
public class test {
    static int a = 1000;
    //...
}
```

Comment: "Cannot make static reference to the non-static field a".

Comment: My bad. It should be static one

Answer (score 0):

In Java, **int is a primitive object** so when you pass it to the test function you actually passing a duplicate of this int.

You can use `IntRef` if you want to pass by refernce.

Answer (score 0):

Both first answers are correct

Read more about Reference vs Value here (Not specifically to Java): [What's the difference between passing by reference vs. passing by value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373419/whats-the-difference-between-passing-by-reference-vs-passing-by-value)

Specifically to Java here: [Is Java "pass-by-reference" or "pass-by-value"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value)

The second solution (adding a static variable called a to you class) may work different. Since you example is quite simple it has the same output. But when you put the static modifier to a variable it will be **shared between all instances of the class**.